# Area for closed questions that are useful with quality answers (avoid deletion)?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm looking at [PNG vs. GIF vs. JPEG - When best to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use):

[image]

The question is a bit open ended and its not about programming *per se*, so its probably best that it was closed. However, I don't think the question was so offensive that it should be deleted, especially given the usefulness of the question and the quality of its answers.

Is there an area that these types of questions can be moved to so they remain a resource for visitors, but don't cross pollinate the site? For example, perhaps there can be a *Purgatory* or *Errata* subdomain or area of Stack Overflow for these sorts of questions.

---

Edit: 08-25-2014. A museum or comedy factory for questions like this would also be welcomed: [By clicking on button, car is not moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491224/by-clicking-on-button-car-is-not-moving). I hope that's not deleted because its got to be one of the classics.

Comment: I’m not so sure we should be creating a separate place for questions that are closed but useful, but rather campaign against the deletion of useful content.

Comment: @icktoofay That. Rather than create another problem to solve this problem, solve this one. Useful content shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: On the Big Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions

Comment: Why don't you just find a location to which the content is *actually acceptable and welcome* rather than trying to figure out how to post a non-specific non-programming problem on a site for specific programming problems.

Comment: We already had that campaign a while ago, @icktoofay: [Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124439)

Comment: @Josh: I’m not surprised. I’m simply saying I don’t think adding another feature is the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations.  By bringing the referenced questions to meta, you managed to attract enough attention to cause their deletion.

I've undeleted the PNG vs GIF question, since it has a very useful answer on it.  You might want to re-evaluate your notion of what is worth keeping, however; the only thing the push-button-car-moving question was good for was to use up one minute of everyone's life who saw it, a minute that they won't get back.

Given the availability of moderators to preserve genuinely useful posts when the community gets it wrong, I don't see the need for a brand new system to preserve the chaff.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can bill me.